# How to migrate from Natara DayNotez for Pocket PC / Windows Mobile

Tags: windows, windows-mobile

I've been using DayNotez as my notes manager since the old Palm PDA days. When I moved to Windows Mobile, I installed DayNotez there and migrated from the Palm version. Now I wish to move from DayNotez altogether (I currently consider Evernote as a decent cross-platform tool).

Problem is, DayNotez doesn't let me export the notes (unless I want to transfer them one by one, which is a pain). Natara offers an export tool for Windows, but it only works for Palm HotSync (as it reads from the backed-up PDB file).

DayNotez Desktop for Windows stores its local DB under "My Documents\Natara\DayNotez\" directory in a file named "[device name] DayNotez.dnz". Quick look within the file spots a string "Standard Jet DB" near the beginning, but I couldn't open it as a regular JET/MDB file.

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I browsed the forums on natara.com (they were down yesterday) and stumbled upon the following useful link, which might answer my question:

http://www.natarasoftware.com/forums/index.php?showtopic=5652

Will try tomorrow and update this question. The tricky part was in specifying the workgroup and the user while opening in MS Access. I'm copying the key part below:

`msaccess.exe "C:\DayNotezTMP\UserName DayNotez.dnz" /wrkgrp "C:\DayNotezTMP\UserName DayNotez.mdw" /user DayNotez`

**Update:** Tried it and it worked for me. I now have all the DayNotez data in a neat Excel and XML files. Will go and figure out Evernote APIs to import all this stuff.